# A question about Functional Analysis : The linear operator is surjective

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

The Question says:

> Let be $\varphi: X \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ linear.  If $\varphi$ isn't null then $\varphi$ is surjectvive.

I have no idea how to do this.
The only thing that I know is that ' how $\varphi$ isn't null, then exists a $\xi \in X$ such that $\varphi (\xi ) = a+ i b \neq 0. $'
But I can't see how this implies that for all $a+ib \in \mathbb{C}$ exists $ x \in X$ satisfying $\varphi (x ) = a+ i b. $

Comment: The image of a linear map is a linear subspace. What are the (nontrivial) linear subspaces of $\mathbb R$?

Answer (score 4):

This is so easy you're going to kick yourself when you figure it out.  What does a linear map do?  It satisfies, among other things, $$\varphi(c \cdot v) = c \cdot \varphi(v)$$ for all complex numbers $c$ and all vectors $v \in X$.  Here $c$ and $\varphi(v)$ are both complex numbers, and they are being multiplied.

Comment: It might help to consider that since $\varphi$ is not null, there's a $v$ for which $\varphi(v) \neq 0.$ Nonetheless, this answer is spot on.

Comment: @D_S thank you.  You are right, I wanna kick myself.